# How to find specific related word from string of java

Tags: java, string

Hi I have a Java String to check for particular word (month). This indicates which date format is used.

For example String is as below:
`SongName=TRIM(@SongName),AlbumName=TRIM(@AlbumName),Month=str_to_date(TRIM(@Month),'%d-%m-%Y'),`

I only know the "Month"-part. The rest is unknown or unavailable for me.
I want `%d-%m-%Y` for the word (Month) out of the string.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ya i tried like  date = string.substring(String.indexOf("(@" + month + "),'"+10 , String.indexOf("(@" + month + "),'"+18 ) its working for some and  sometime gives output   like '%d-%m-%  and all  means if space is there then its counting that also i used trim() but no luck

Comment: Many questions arise here... Is the string always like this? I mean, this looks like the config of 3rd party application. Are you sure that the snippet `Month=str_to_date(TRIM(@Month)), '%d-%m-%Y')` is always there? And slightly off-topic: what does it mean? What is the expected result of formatting `April` as `'%d-%m-%Y'`, for instance?

Comment: Month is just name of parameter and its linux script i am reading using java  ya if its timestamp datatype is there in script means  date format would be there might be possible more then one then i need to fetch particular dateformat of the  parameter available part would be only name of parameter for example Month here

Answer (score 0):

REGEX Pattern:
`@Month\\),'(\\.+?)'\\)`
I did not test it, but it should do. This regex extracts one or more characters of "any char" between @Month),' and '). Part you are looking for will be in group 1.